# Python Hangman - "for" loop replaces all characters, not just correct ones

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, replace

In my understanding of the function below, if a user types "z" it should loop through each of the characters in "zebra"; **if** the character matches the user's input it should replace the corresponding character in user_word (the blank word) with the user's entry. Otherwise, it should do nothing and continue to loop through the word "zebra".

So, if the user guesses a "z", it should recognize that "z" is character 0 in variable **word** , and then replace character 0 in **user_word** ("_____") with a "z".

Instead, if a user guesses any correct letter, it replaces each character in "_____" with the user's input. So, if user_guess = "z", user_word prints as "zzzzz". If he/she guesses "e", user_word prints as "eeeee", and so on.

I've followed the logic of the program, step by step, and on paper it seems like it should work. What am I doing wrong below?

I know there's way too many "if/else" statements below, and I do intend to condense some of it under separate functions (like a "correctguess()" function).

```
word = "zebra"

def hangman(word):

    user_word = "_" * len(word)
    incorrect_guesses = []
    failed_guesses = 0
    user_guess = getuser()

    while user_word != word and failed_guesses < 10:
        if user_guess in word:
            for char in word:
                if char == user_guess:
                    user_word = user_word.replace(user_word[word.index(char)], user_guess)
        else:
            incorrect_guesses.append(user_guess)
            failed_guesses += 1

        print "Word: ", user_word
        print "Letters missed: ", ', '.join(incorrect_guesses)
        user_guess = getuser()

    if user_guess == word:
        print "Awesome, you got it! You win!"

    else:
        print "That's ten tries, your dude is hanging from the gallows. You lose :("
```

Comment: Do you know what `replace` does? It replaces *all* occurrences of the first parameter. So if the first one is `_` it will replace all the underscores.

Comment: Willem, I did not realize that - I thought that if the first parameter was entered as an index in the string, it would replace only that index. Is there a wayto do this?

Comment: Pravitha V, the getuser() is a separate function which gets the user's input (a letter) and checks whether it's a valid entry. If it's not, it prompts the user to enter another value. I figured it would be cleaner to put it under a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is located here:

```
for char in word:
    if char == user_guess:
        user_word = user_word.replace(user_word[word.index(char)], user_guess)
```

If the character `char` is indeed the character of `user_guess`, then `user_word[word.index(char)]` will be the underscore character `'_'`, so you call:

```
user_word = user_word.replace('_',user_guess)
```

so that means that you will replace **all** underscores with `user_guess`, regardless whether these are located at the positions where the `user_guess` is located in `word`.

You can use the following expression instead of the `for` loop:

```
user_word = ''.join(w if w == user_guess else u for u,w in zip(user_word,word))
```

This works as follows: a string is *iterable*. If you write a loop around a string, you iterate over the characters. By using `zip`, we construct tuples of the two iterables. So here the initial run will produce `('_', 'z'), ('_', 'e'), ('_', 'b'), ('_', 'r'), ('_', 'a')`. For each of these tuples, we unpack these in `u,w` (so the first iteration `u = '_'`, and `w='z'`).

We then use a ternary operator `w if w == user_guess else u`. The ternary operator will thus check if the character `w` of `word` is the same as the `user_guess`. In case that is, we know replace the character with `w`, otherwise we yield `u`.

The iterable that we produce with this expression thus generates characters, and we `''.join(..)` these together.

So the correct program is:

```
word = "zebra"

def hangman(word):

    user_word = "_" * len(word)
    incorrect_guesses = []
    failed_guesses = 0
    user_guess = getuser()

    while user_word != word and failed_guesses < 10:
        if user_guess in word:
            user_word = ''.join(w if w == user_guess else u for u,w in zip(user_word,word))
        else:
            incorrect_guesses.append(user_guess)
            failed_guesses += 1

        print "Word: ", user_word
        print "Letters missed: ", ', '.join(incorrect_guesses)
        user_guess = getuser()

    if user_guess == word:
        print "Awesome, you got it! You win!"

    else:
        print "That's ten tries, your dude is hanging from the gallows. You lose :("
```

If I set `getuser = input`, I get the following run:

```
>>> hangman('zebra')
a
Word:  ____a
Letters missed:  
b
Word:  __b_a
Letters missed:  
c
Word:  __b_a
Letters missed:  c
d
Word:  __b_a
Letters missed:  c, d
e
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d
f
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f
g
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f, g
h
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f, g, h
i
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f, g, h, i
j
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f, g, h, i, j
k
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f, g, h, i, j, k
l
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f, g, h, i, j, k, l
m
Word:  _eb_a
Letters missed:  c, d, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m
n
That's ten tries, your dude is hanging from the gallows. You lose :(
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I understood this correctly, the best way to go about changing single elements in strings is to convert the word to a list, and then reassign the values.

Comment: @Max: we do not convert it to a list. A string is iterable: if you iterate over it, you obtain the characters. We zip them together with the `word` and check if the `word` char corresponds to the input char. In case it does, we use that char, otherwise we use the "old" char. We join these characters then together.

Answer (score 0):

## .replace() doesn't do what you think it does

`.replace` replaces all occurrences of the first `paramater` with the second. So to give an example:

```
"sentence".replace("e", "z")
```

would give:

```
"szntzncz"
```

What you want to do in your program is when looping through each `char` is replace the **index of** that char not all underscores `_` with the `char`.

To replace the index of a string, you need to convert it to a list with `list()` and then change the `index` you want then finally convert back to a string with `''.join()`.

So the line:

```
user_word = user_word.replace(user_word[word.index(char)], user_guess)
```

should be instead:

```
user_word = list(user_word)
user_word[word.index(char)] = user_guess
user_word = ''.join(user_word)
```

and that will give you the right placement of `z` in the 5 underscores.

It may also be worth considering to just store the word as `chars` in a list anyway as that will mean you don't have to bother with the conversion each time a letter is guessed. If you do store it in a list, you just have to remember to print: `''.join(user_word)` when displaying it for the user. :)

Comment: Sorry, about the mistake, I got confused and thought that strings where `muatable`! I've fixed it now by converting to a list, changing the indexed item and then converting back to a string